# Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type (no reference error)

Tags: c#

I've seen a couple answers here, but it hasn't helped me solve the problem. I have both using System.Linq and using System.Data.Entity (greyed out). I have:

```
internal virtual GlobalTable GetGlobalTableById(int newTableId)
{
    return UnitOfWork.GlobalTableRepository.Get(
               x => x.NewTableId == newTableId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It wants me to create this in my IGlobalTableRepository:

```
object Get(Func<object, object> p);
```

I have this in my IGlobalTableRepository:

```
GlobalTable Get(int newTableId);
```

but that just creates another problem afterwards. I'm stuck on options here.

Here is a class from the repository:

```
public GlobalTable Get(int newTableId)
{
    var o = Get(x => x.NewTableId == newTableId).FirstOrDefault();
    return o;
}
```

Comment: You should just call Get method of `IGlobalTableRepository` with `newTableId` passed to it. Why,can't you do that?

Comment: What is the error you receive? Do you want to convert `Get` into a `Func<object, object>`?

Comment: No I don't, the error is Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Keith Post a `GlobalTableRepository` class

Comment: ok posted up top

Comment: You're passing a delegate type `Func<object,object>` to a method that accepts an `int`. Should be `return UnitOfWork.GlobalTableRepository.Get(newTableId).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Yeah that worked somehow. Not sure how, but it did lol

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how variance works with delegates in C#. You cannot use that lambda as a `Func<object, object>` because it accesses a member of the `x` that is not a member of `object`. You need to cast the `x` of your lambda expression to its specific type.

Like
`x => ((MyType)x).Member == foo`

Comment: Int does not define NewTableId. What class is that on?

Comment: You need to cast x not the result

Comment: public partial class GlobalTableService : ServerBase, IGlobalTableService